# Laptop screen is black when on battery

Tags: laptop, battery, lcd, blank-screen

On my Lenovo Ideapad LCD screen is black while on battery, OK when powered by AC adapter.
Only LCD is off with battery, also while booting, in BIOS, in Windows. If I connect adapter screen immidietally comes on. Like backlight is not working on battery?